# TypeError while executing Binary tree code

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am getting an error while testing the following function. Can anybody help me with this?

code:

```
class treenode(object):

def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    
def largest_leaf_value(tnode):
    if tnode is None:
        return None
    res = tnode.data
    lres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.left)
    rres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.right)
    if lres > res:
        res = lres
    if rres > res:
        res = rres
    return res
```

Here's the test script:

```
# test tree with 1 level i.e. root value only
input_tree = T.treenode(1)
expected = 3

result = a8q1.largest_leaf_value(input_tree)
assert result is expected, "{}: copying empty tree returned unexpected result".format(test_item)

# test a longer tree
input_tree = T.treenode(1, T.treenode(2, T.treenode(3, T.treenode(4, T.treenode(5)))))
expected = 5

result = a8q1.largest_leaf_value(input_tree)
assert result is expected, "{}: copying empty tree returned unexpected result".format(test_item)
```

And here's the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/CMPT 145/Assignment 8/a8q1_testing.py", line 60, in <module>
    result = a8q1.largest_leaf_value(input_tree)
  File "D:\CMPT 145\Assignment 8\a8q1.py", line 44, in largest_leaf_value
    if lres > res:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Please let me know why is this happening?

Comment: `if tnode is None:
        return` here is where you return None. Next step is to use this None in > expression. This is the root of the bug

Comment: I modified the code to return when tnode is empty, but I didnt understand the part where you said use None is '>' expression, can you please elaborate or give me an example?

Comment: what does `largest_leaf_value` return if `tnode` is None?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention in the previous comment, It returns None

Comment: Yes - it return None. Now you take this None and compare it to a something using `>`. This is the bug

Comment: I dont get it. Compare it with what and how? Could you please provide an example code so I can understand? that would be helpful

Comment: `if lres > res` do you understand that lres can be None?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not following you at all.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: When you do `if lres > res:` what are those values? `res = tnode.data` and `lres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.left)`. Now, what happens when `tnode` is a leaf? The call to `largest_leaf_value(tnode.left)` will be like `largest_leaf_value(None)` so the function will execute `if tnode is None: return None` So going back to the start we now have `lres = None`. So you're trying to do `if None > tnode.data:` which can't work

Comment: I understand but how can I fix the code then?
Because I have looked up other sources and exactn given code has produced desired output, but when I try to execute the program it throws and error. That is why I am asking for examples to fix the code

Comment: You need to add some additional `if` statements to check if either `lres` or `rres` is `None`.

Comment: The first test in the test script is wrong. Why would the expected output be 3 for a list with one node that has value 1???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `largest_leaf_value` will return `None` in its recursion base case, you need to be ready for `lres` or `rres` to get `None` assigned to them.

The type error occurs on the lines where you compare `lres` or `rres` with `res`, and tells you that a `None` value cannot be compared with `res`.

So you have two possibilities: either avoid that comparison from executing when `lres` or `rres` is `None`, or, don't let your function return `None`, but instead return -infinity (since that value is smaller than all other finite numerical values).

Solution with the first approach:

```
def largest_leaf_value(tnode):
    if tnode is None:
        return None
    res = tnode.data
    lres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.left)
    rres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.right)
    # Only compare when not None:
    if lres is not None and lres > res:
        res = lres
    if rres is not None and rres > res:
        res = rres
    return res
```

Solution with the second approach:

```
def largest_leaf_value(tnode):
    if tnode is None:
        # Don't return None, but -infinity
        return float("-inf")
    res = tnode.data
    lres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.left)
    rres = largest_leaf_value(tnode.right)
    if lres > res:
        res = lres
    if rres > res:
        res = rres
    return res
```

Note that this will behave differently when you pass an empty tree (i.e. `None`) as argument in the initial call. Mathematically it is not defined what the maximum is in an empty collection, so it will depend on what you expect to happen in that case.

Finally, you can use `max()` to make the second version a bit shorter:

```
def largest_leaf_value(tnode):
    return (float("-inf") if tnode is None else
        max(tnode.data, largest_leaf_value(tnode.left), largest_leaf_value(tnode.right))
    )
```